# Detect alternating signs

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a nice and short way to tell whether a python list (or numpy array) contains numbers with alternating signs? In other words:

```
is_alternating_signs([1, -1, 1, -1, 1]) == True
is_alternating_signs([-1, 1, -1, 1, -1]) == True
is_alternating_signs([1, -1, 1, -1, -1]) == False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, thanks to SO "related" feature. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652368/how-to-detect-a-sign-change-for-elements-in-a-numpy-array) and adopted the answer by [ianalis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100217/ianalis) and the comment by [lazyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/566644/lazyr)

```
def is_alternating_signs(a):
    return numpy.all(numpy.abs(numpy.diff(numpy.sign(a))) == 2)



print is_alternating_signs([1, -1, 1, -1, 1]) 
print is_alternating_signs([-1, 1, -1, 1, -1]) 
print is_alternating_signs([1, -1, 1, -1, -1])
```

The output is

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: This is also `True` for `[0,1,0,1,0]`. My suggestion: `numpy.all(numpy.abs(numpy.diff(numpy.sign(a))) == 2)`

Answer (score 3):

You could check every even member is negative and every odd member is positive by taking a slice of every second item, starting at either the beginning or from position one.  Also test the reverse to cover both possibilities.

so:

```
def is_alternating_signs(l):
    return ( (all(x<0 for x in l[::2]) and all(x>=0 for x in l[1::2])) or
             (all(x>=0 for x in l[::2]) and all(x<0 for x in l[1::2])))
```

Comment: It really depends how we define "alternating signs" - I could see either way depending on whether you group zero with the nonnegatives (ie taking "sign" as whether we'd generally write it with a negative sign) or put it in its own signless category.  (Though in that case, you could also potentially even argue that [1,0,1,0] is "alternating signs")

Answer (score 1):

Using [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module and [is_signed](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.is_signed) method:

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = [1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
b = [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
c = [1, -1, 1, -1, -1]

def is_alternating_signs(values):
    lVals = [Decimal(val).is_signed() for val in values]
    prevVal = lVals.pop(0)
    for val in lVals:
        if prevVal == val:
            return False
        prevVal = val
    return True

is_alternating_signs(a)
is_alternating_signs(b)
is_alternating_signs(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like pairwise:

```
from itertools import izip, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b)
    return izip(a, b)

def is_alternating_signs(iterable):
    return all(x < 0 < y or x > 0 > y for x, y in pairwise(iterable))
```

If there are no zeros in `iterable` this also works:

```
def is_alternating_signs(iterable):
    return all((x < 0) == (0 < y) for x, y in pairwise(iterable))
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like...

```
def is_alternating_signs(aList):
    return all( (aList[i]^aList[i-1])<0 for i in range(1,len(aList)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just the straight-forward solution by looping through it once and testing? Quite possibly the fastest, too, because many of the other solutions loop through the list multiple times.

```
def signs_are_alternating(numbers):
    """Return True if numbers in given list have alternating signs, False
    otherwise. If given list has less than 2 elements, return False.

    >>> signs_are_alternating([1, -1, 1, -1, 1])
    True
    >>> signs_are_alternating([-1, 1, -1, 1, -1])
    True
    >>> signs_are_alternating([1, -1, 1, -1, -1])
    False

    """
    if len(numbers) < 2:
        return False
    previous_positive = (numbers[0] < 0)  # Pretend it starts alternating
    for number in numbers:
        this_positive = (number >= 0)
        if previous_positive == this_positive:
            return False
        previous_positive = this_positive
    return True
```

Note that I wasn't quite sure what the intended behaviour is if the input list has less than 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my one-liner, which is probably less efficient than some of the other suggestions:

```
def is_alternating_signs(lst):
    return all(x * y < 0 for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```