# Label a pandas column based on sign flips of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Index High Low MA(5)-MA(20) 
  0    100  90    -1
  1    101  91    -2
  2    102  92    +1
  3    99   88    +2
```

I want to get the maximum of the highs when MA(5) - MA(20) is positive, and the minimum of the lows then the same is negative.

The thing is that I want only the local maxima and minima not the global one, so, getting the maximum and minimum has to be reset each time the sign of MA(5) - MA(20) flips.

I do not want to use a for loop since they are really slow in python.

Any help?

Comment: Interesting question, possibly related/helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652368/how-to-detect-a-sign-change-for-elements-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.sign` to get the sign of the last column. Perform a `groupby` operation, and use `np.where` to assign values accordingly.

```
v = np.sign(df['MA(5)-MA(20)']) < 1
g = df.groupby(v.ne(v.shift()).cumsum()) 

df['Maxima/Minima'] =  np.where(
       v, g.Low.transform('min'), g.High.transform('max')
)
```

```
df

   Index  High  Low  MA(5)-MA(20)  Maxima/Minima
0      0   100   90            -1             90
1      1   101   91            -2             90
2      2   102   92             1            102
3      3    99   88             2            102
```

You'll notice that rows are assigned the *local* minima/maxima values according to their sign.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?

```
v=df['MA(5)-MA(20)'].gt(0).astype(int).diff().fillna(0).cumsum()

df.groupby(v).High.transform('max').mask(df['MA(5)-MA(20)'] == 0,df.groupby(v).Low.transform('min'))

0     90
1     90
2    102
3    102
Name: High, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I guess you meant to invert the condition. `df['MA(5)-MA(20)']==0` returns the right answer ;)