# Counting number of consecutive occurences of numbers in a series

Tags: python, numpy

I've a series (1 dimension array) of numbers, say 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...

Is there an elegant (and preferrably fastest) way of counting the number of consecutive occurences of 1 or 0 before it changes? So for this the result would be (0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1), (1, 4), ...

Comment: Don't think you can do better than O(n)

Comment: @ThomasKowalski, then just the elegant:) Because it's always possible to iterate, counting and keeping the value of the current item, but maybe there's a combination of ready numpy functions which I haven't found, looking in the docs…

Comment: If either of the posted solutions has worked for you, considering accepting the best among them?

Comment: @Divakar, I don't care about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another with NumPy, specifically making use of array-slicing -

```
def islands_info(a):
    # Compare consecutive elems for changes. Use `True` as sentients to detect edges
    idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,a[:-1]!=a[1:],True])

    # Index into input array with the sliced array until second last array to
    # get start indices and the differentiation for the lengths
    return np.column_stack((a[idx[:-1]],np.diff(idx)))
```

Sample run -

```
In [51]: a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [52]: islands_info(a)
Out[52]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 4]])
```

If you need the output as list of tuples -

```
In [56]: list(zip(*islands_info(a).T))
Out[56]: [(0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1), (1, 4)]
```

Timings -

Comparing against the other NumPy based one by [`@yatu`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56644280/) -

```
In [43]: np.random.seed(a)

In [44]: a = np.random.choice([0,1], 1000000)

In [45]: %timeit yatu(a)
11.7 ms ± 428 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit islands_info(a)
8.98 ms ± 40.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [47]: np.random.seed(a)

In [48]: a = np.random.choice([0,1], 10000000)

In [49]: %timeit yatu(a)
232 ms ± 3.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [50]: %timeit islands_info(a)
152 ms ± 933 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: In my setup `islands_info` returns a zip object instead of `[(0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1), (1, 4)]`. Is this due to different Python version?

Comment: @Brenlla Yeah on Pyth3.x, you need to wrap it with `list()`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `groupby` from `itertools`

```py
from itertools import groupby
x = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
occ = [(i, len([*y,])) for i,y in groupby(x)]
```

Outputs :

```py
In [23]: [(i, len([*y,])) for i,y in groupby(x)]
Out[23]: [(1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3)]
```

Comment: Or (with a little help of more_itertools) simply: `[(i, ilen(y)) for i,y in groupby(x)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `NumPy` one for a good performance:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# indexes where changes take place
changes = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a)!=0)
#include initial and end index
ix = np.r_[0,changes+1,a.shape[0]]
# index the array with changes to check the value in question
# stack with the count of values, taking the diff over ix
np.column_stack([np.r_[a[changes], a[a.shape[0]-1]], np.diff(ix)])

array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

---

Timings:

```
def yatu(a):
    changes = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a)!=0)
    ix = np.r_[0,changes+1,a.shape[0]]
    return np.column_stack([np.r_[a[changes], a[a.shape[0]-1]], np.diff(ix)])

def groupby(a):
    return [(i, len([*y,])) for i,y in groupby(a)]

a = np.random.choice([0,1], 10_000)

%timeit groupby(list(a))
# 1.83 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit yatu(a)
# 150 µs ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Aha, thank you. I'll play with it. Myself was considering something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652368/how-to-detect-a-sign-change-for-elements-in-a-numpy-array if I subtract 0.5 from the sequence.

Comment: You're welcome! This should perform quite nicely. Trying with a k=10_000 length sequence and takes about 100us @aikipooh

Comment: Still a bit arcane though for my peace of mind (and that of the future users of the codebase) =:P

Answer (score 0):

I used `reduce` from `functools`, `groupby` shown by Ayoub is probably better (and faster), because this one copies the accumulator each time.

```py
from functools import reduce

l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
p = lambda acc, x : acc[:-1] + [(x, acc[-1][1] + 1)] if acc and x == acc[-1][0] else acc + [(x, 1)]
result = reduce(p, l, [])

print(result)
```

> [(0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1), (1, 4)]

Comment: Oh my! It's too arcane, and yes, I was hoping for something from numpy to be faster as well (the real sequence shall be around 2k in len).

Comment: This one is very Haskell like, for Python you should definitely go with the other option yes